# Application fails with "Compiling Vertex shader failed"

Tags: qt, opengl, qt5, qt5.2

I'm using Qt 5.2.1 and have compiled it for OpenGL (using build-option "-opengl desktop"). Now when I try to use a component that should make use of OpenGL, it fails with a

```
qFatal("Compiling Vertex shader failed")
```

All other Qt-applications that do not use OGL still work fine. The test-application mentioned above is just a ready-to use demo, no self-written crap.

Any idea what the reason could be or what I could check to find out what's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: the vertex shader isn't valid for some reason, check the compile output log from openGL to see why

Comment: ratchet freak: where does this log go to when compiling for Windows?

Comment: You need to ask for it after compilation of the vertex shader at runtime

Comment: QOpenGLShaderProgram::log() returns an empty log, so this does not give the reason...

Answer (score 0):

Windows only supports DirectX and OpenGl 1.1 by default. You'll get this error, among others, if you don't have proper OpenGL drivers installed.

Try installing drivers from your graphics card's vendor web site (not the ones installed by Windows automatically), which should include a proper opengl32.dll.

Using Qt with ANGLE would also solve it, if this is your problem.

Comment: Ich checked this using an other application that makes use of OpenGL and it works, so drivers does not seem to be a problem. Btw: is there a HWOTO available somewhere describing building with ANGLE? The information in Qt Wiki is a bit thrifty, just telling ANGLE is needed...

Comment: OK, I'm a bit closer, I found a log output "Warning: Flat qualifier not supported on your platform's GLSL language. Requires at least GLSL version 1.2 with GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 extension". Could this be the driver issue?

Comment: It shows a limited driver, but if you get that far the problem might be caused by something else. To build with angle just don't pass the -opengl switch to configure.

Comment: jturcotte: Dropping the -opengl switch leads to an error "Cannot open include file: 'GLES2/gl2.h': No such file or directory". The file is there...but where do I have to configure the path to this directory?

Comment: configure probably disables it if you don't have the DirectX SDK installed. See http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building-Qt-5-from-Git#aea23489ce3aa9b6406ebb28e0cda430